# Is there a way to make phaser game object into a react controlled component?

Tags: reactjs, phaser-framework

I'm trying to make a web game using react to work as the UI part of the game, and use phaser 3 as the engine. I've integrated phaser and react with ion-phaser/react, and it works well if all the data is there when the phaser app is ran, however I can't figure out if I can feed data to the phaser app while it's running.

For example:

```
const GameEngine = ({width, backgroundColor}) => {
  const state = { /* ... game config */ };
  let {initialize, game} = state;

  return <IonPhaser game={game} initialize={initialize} />;
};
```

this works well if the props width and background are provided, but when they change, phaser doesn't update. Is there a way to continually feed data in the game from outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to publish events to Phaser's event system from React. This is pretty straightforward if you already have a reference to the Phaser `game` object in your React component.

In your React component, you could do something like:

```js
game.events.emit('MY_EVENT', 'Hello world!')
```

Then, in any Phaser scene, you could do something like:

```js
this.game.events.on('MY_EVENT', (event) => {
  console.log(event)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with this issue.
Ended up settling for a hacky workaround. 
Defined the game config object outside of the React state and keep checking for the instance keys existence on the game config object. See the getInstance function below:

```
import React from "react";
import Phaser from "phaser";
import { IonPhaser } from "@ion-phaser/react";

const game = {
    /* ... game config */ 
};

function getInstance() {
    if (game.instance) {
    console.log("ready")
    return Promise.resolve(game.instance);
    } else {
    console.log("waiting")
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (game.instance) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            resolve(game.instance);
        }
        });
    }, 30);
    }
}

export default class GameEngine extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isReady: false,
    };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    getInstance().then((instance) => {
        console.log(instance)
        this.setState({ isReady: true });
    });
    }


    render() {
    const { initialize } = this.props;
    return (
        <IonPhaser
        game={game}
        initialize={initialize}
        />
    );
    }
}
```

I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/proyecto26/ion-phaser/issues/21) on the GitHub ion-phaser project

Answer (score 0):

Following up to Ben's answer... For anybody coming here wondering how to get the `game` object... I added this to my code to get it working as an example. It's specific to my setup, but should be helpful to others:

in App.js:

- `import { useRef } from 'react';`
- in function App() you'll want: `const gameRef = useRef(null)`
- pass it to your IonPhaser component: `<MyIonPhaserComponent gameRef={gameRef} ...`

in your IonPhaser component:

```
...
return (
        <>
            <IonPhaser ref={gameRef} ...
        </>
)

...
```

in whatever other react component you want to emit events from, pass it `gameRef={gameRef}` as well, then use it with:

```
var PhaserGameInstance = gameRef.current.getInstance().then( game => phaserGameObject = game);

someFunctionToCallOnClick(){
  phaserGameObject.events.emit("MY_CUSTOM_EVENT", "hello");
}
```

If not in a function, the phaserGameObject will probably be undefined until the `getInstance()` resolves

Then back in the game setup in MyIonPhaserComponent, within the `create` function:

```
this.game.events.on('MY_CUSTOM_EVENT', (event) => {
  console.log(event)
})
```

At this point, your other react component should emit events that are immediately picked up within Phaser

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest another approach, here's phaser3+react+websocket template, use this repository as sample. Key feature is two dimensional functionality, you can call react controls from your scene. To call react hooks outside react components:

```
CONTROLS.setVersion(`Phaser v${Phaser.VERSION}`)
```

To call phaser from react component you can use(import global variable from phaser.game.ts):

```
import game from "./phaser-game"
(game.scene.game as GameScene).<whatever you want>
```

https://github.com/tfkfan/phaser3-react-template